# Azure function: Entity Framework Core: A second operation started on this context before a previous operation completed

Tags: c#, azure, asynchronous, dependency-injection, parallel-processing

In my Azure functions I am using EF Core and I am getting this error:

> Entity Framework Core: A second operation started on this context before a previous operation completed

My code in `program.cs` is as follows:

```
public static void Main()
{
    System.Text.Encoding.RegisterProvider(System.Text.CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);

    var host = new HostBuilder()
                .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()
                .ConfigureServices(s =>
                {
                    s.AddDbContext<HumanRisksDbContext>(o =>
                        o.UseSqlServer(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ConnectionStrings:HumanRisksDbContext")),
                        ServiceLifetime.Transient);
                 
                    s.AddSingleton<IAuditApiService, AuditApiService>();
                })
                .Build();

    host.Run();
}
```

Now I have three Azure functions which can overlap when running.

Each of these functions access the same service class which is like this

```
public class AuditApiService : IAuditApiService
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
    private readonly ILogHandler _logHandler;
    private readonly HumanRisksDbContext context;

    public AuditApiService(IConfiguration configuration,
        ILogHandler logHandler,
        HumanRisksDbContext context)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
        _logHandler = logHandler;
        this.context = context;
    }
}
```

This class has three public functions which uses the context.

Here is function one

```
public async Task Process(string appServer)
{
    // Go through active controls
    foreach (var control in ActiveControls(context).Where(c => c.TaskType.Equals(Controls.TASK_TYPE.Interval)))
    {
        try
        {
           // some processing

            AuditRepository auditRepository = new AuditRepository(context);
            await auditRepository.Create(upcoming, _logHandler);
            await context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Function two is like this

```
public async Task ProcessLate(string appServer)
{
    // Go through all audits older than now that is not completed
    foreach (var audit in NotCompletedAuditsBeforeToday(context))
    {
        try
        {
            // processing
            await context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            LogHandlerService.Log("Error process late audits id=" + (audit?.Id) + ": " + err.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

And the last function is like this

```
public void ProcessReport(string appServer)
{
    UserRepository userrep = new UserRepository(context);

    var administratorRole =  context.Roles.Where(w => w.Name.Equals(Roles.Administrator.ToString())).SingleOrDefault();
    var managerRole =  context.Roles.Where(w => w.Name.Equals(Roles.Manager.ToString())).SingleOrDefault();
    var employeeRole =  context.Roles.Where(w => w.Name.Equals(Roles.Employee.ToString())).SingleOrDefault();

    // Todo: should we have is null check here on administratorRole?

    // Find users in either an administrator or manager role
    var administrators = userrep.ListByRole(context, administratorRole.Id);
    // var administrators = context.Users.Include(w => w.ro.Where(u => u.Roles.Select(r => r.RoleId).Contains(administratorRole.Id)).ToList();

    var managers = userrep.ListByRole(context, managerRole.Id);
    // context.Users.Where(u => u.Roles.Select(r => r.RoleId).Contains(managerRole.Id)).ToList();

    administrators.AddRange(managers);

    // processing

    var employees = userrep.ListByRole(context, employeeRole.Id);

    // processing
}
```

Am I missing something? If these functions are called at the same time would it be an issue?

Comment: by injecting the context into a singleton, you have by extension made the context a singleton as well. A [Captive Dependency](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/02/captive-dependency/)

Comment: How did I do that? And how can I fix that? :) @Nkosi

Comment: What is `ActiveControls(context)`?